# Помогите найти библиотеку, реализующую функцию поиска

Tags: java, android

Мне нужна библиотека, которая реализовывала бы функцию поиска как, например, в Яндексе или Гугле — начинаешь вводить символы и сразу выпадает список релевантных слов (допустим, из массива в приложении, это уже детали). С возможностью обработать тач по слову / фразе из списка.

В идеале хотелось бы увидеть библиотеку с возможностью добавления зависимости maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот функционал есть в SDK – [`AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Пример:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

Как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! Обязательно попробую.